# how do I get AutoMapper AssertConfigurationIsValid() to detect new unmapped source properties

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

I am consuming a simple JSON REST API and binding to a very simple class, then using AutoMapper to map to a more complex DTO class converting strings to DateTime's, string to Enums, etc...

If I add a new property to sourceDTO class then AssertConfigurationIsValid() correctly throws AutoMapperConfigurationException "Unmapped members were found.".

I'm thinking ahead for when new properties may get added to the REST API endpoint, another developer (or myself) may add the new property to the source class but could forget to add the corresponding property to the DTO class...

If I create a reverse map (which can be complex due to the manipulation I am doing, plus I will never use it anyway as the API is one-way only) then the validation obviously works and any new properties added to the source class will cause a validation error.

My question, do I **have** to create a ReverseMap to be able to detect when source properties aren't correctly mapped to a corresponding DTO property? Or is there some magic method/overload/setting I have missed?

Note: I'm using latest AutoMapper (v8) via dependency injection in .NET Core.

```
using AutoMapper;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyService
    {
        readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public MyService(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }

        public sourceDTO TestMap()
        {
            var src = new source { name = "bob" };
            return _mapper.Map<sourceDTO>(src);
        }
    }

    public class source
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        //more complex properties stripped for brevity...

        //problem: how to get AssertConfigurationIsValid to throw a validation error without having to create a reverse map
        //public int someId { get; set; }
    }

    public class sourceDTO
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        //more complex properties stripped for brevity...

        //note: if I uncomment this property then AssertConfigurationIsValid correctly points out the mapping isn't 1-to-1
        //public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestProfile : Profile
    {
        public TestProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<source, sourceDTO>();
            //note: if I create a reverse map then AssertConfigurationIsValid picks up unmapped properties - but do I have to do this?
            //CreateMap<sourceDTO, source>();
        }
    }
}
```

*Update:* The solution to my problem was to change;

```
CreateMap<source, sourceDTO>();
```

to;

```
CreateMap<source, sourceDTO>(MemberList.Source);
```

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html#selecting-members-to-validate). But you cannot have both at the same time with a single map.

Comment: thanks @LucianBargaoanu that's what I was looking for, I only need 1-way validation :)